# Laravel Queue not sending the variables to the blade file

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-queue

I am trying to send bulk email using mailables and Laravel Queue. I am passing subject and message as a variable. When I am not using queue there is no problem email is sent perfectly, but doing this operation is interrupted when http connection is closed(i.e. browser is closed).

The problem occurs when I use queue, that the variable is not passed to blade template.

**Controller**

```
public function newsletter(Request $request)
    {
        $job = (new SendNewsLetter($request->all()))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5));
        dispatch($job);

        Session::flash('message', 'Email Sent');
        Session::flash('class', 'success');
        return redirect()->route('news');
    }
```

**Jobs**

```
    public $tries = 1; 

    public $request;

    public function __construct($request)
    {
        //
        $this->request = $request;
        $request = $this->request;
    }

    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        $data = array(
            'message' => $request->message,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'file' => $request->file("file")
        );
        //dd($data);
        $teachingLevel = $request->highest_teaching_level;
        $school = $request->school;
        $province = $request->province;
        $district = $request->district;

        $subject = $request->subject;

        if ($teachingLevel != "" && $school != "" && $province != "" && $district != "") {
            $email = User::where('highest_teaching_level', $teachingLevel)->where('current_school_name', $school)->where('address','LIKE', '%'.$province.'%')->where('address','LIKE', '%'.$district.'%')->pluck('email');
        }else{
        $email = User::pluck('email');
        }
        
        foreach($email as $e)
        {
            Mail::to($e)->send(new NewsLetter($data, $subject));
        }
    }
```

**Mail**

```
    public $data;
    public $subject;

    public function __construct($data, $subject)
    {
        //
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $name = 'test';
        //dd($name);
        if ($this->data['file'] != "") {
            # code...
            return $this->subject($this->subject)->markdown('mail.newsletter')->with('data', $this->data)->attach($this->data['file']->getRealPath(), [
                'as' => $this->data['file']->getClientOriginalName()
            ]);
        }else{
            //dd($this->subject);
            return $this->subject($name)->markdown('mail.newsletter')->with('data', $this->data);
        }

    }
```

I reviewed multiple answer like this one -> [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/passing-data-to-queue-job-class?page=1)

But is is not working the variable is not passed to the blade templates is it the problem with the way variable is stored.

My alternative plan is to store the message in DB first and retrieve the data from there

Answer (score 0):

Please make your `__construct` function and `handle` function as below.

```
public function __construct($request)
{
    //
    $this->request = $request;
    
}

public function handle()
{
    $request = $this->request;
    //to see what you're getting \Log::info([$request]);
    //rest of the logic.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use "this" when you work with properties of class.

```
public function __construct($request)
{
    //
    $this->request = $request;
    $request = $this->request; REMOVE IT
}
///
    $data = array(
        'message' => $this->request->message,
        'subject' => $this->request->subject,
        'file' => $this->request->file("file")
    );
```

Secondly there is a big chance that you forgot to execute the command after your changes were added.

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment